# More efficient map overlays in Android

Tags: android, overlay, android-mapview

In my app I am drawing bus routes on top of a [MapView](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView.html). The routes have anywhere between a dozen and a few hundred GPS coordinates that describe the route that the bus takes.

[image: Hosted by imgur.com]

The problem I'm having is that once I draw out all these lines panning/zooming the `MapView` is incredibly slow (even clicking the 'Back' button takes a minute to happen).

I'm not sure how relevant it is, but I put in some debug code then checked the logcat output and the `MapView` is repeatedly calling the `draw()` method of the [Overlay](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/Overlay.html) whether anything has changed or not. This is happening several times a second and is causing a massive amount of garbage collection to happen (2-3 MB every second).

Does anyone have any ideas/suggestions for a method to try and speed this up?

Comment: Is it possible you are overriding the wrong method? [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792263/draw-is-being-constantly-called-in-my-android-map-overlay) you find a good explanation of the topic...

Answer (score 5):

I have only used `ItemizedOverlay`, not `Overlay`, so these suggestions are pure conjecture. Heck, I haven't even done much with the 2D graphics API.

Obviously, the best answer is to get it to stop calling `draw()` all the time. Try logging some stack traces and see if you can figure out what is triggering all of the `draw()` calls. For example, in the Android Google Groups recently, somebody noticed that `Chronometer` causes widgets in the same UI to be redrawn every second. While I can see you don't have a `Chronometer`, you might be able to figure out some root cause to the `draw()` calls that you can correct.

Assuming that does not help, I am guessing that the test for "whether anything has changed or not" is some combination of `getLatitudeSpan()`, `getLongitudeSpan()`, `getZoomLevel()`, and maybe other `MapView` methods. And, I am assuming that on every `draw()` you are iterating over your GPS points and drawing the route. If so, you could try:

1. When you really do draw, draw first to a `Canvas` backed by a `Bitmap`, then apply the `Bitmap` on the `Canvas` you are handed in `draw()`, and cache that `Bitmap`.
2. Track what combination of values were used in the last `draw()`, and if the next `draw()` is the same, just reuse the existing `Bitmap`. Else, go to step #1, making sure to release the Bitmap (or reuse it, if that's possible).

I am guessing that with graphics acceleration, blasting a `Bitmap` onto the `Canvas` is cheaper than iterating over the coordinates and drawing lines. And, by caching the `Bitmap`, you will save on garbage generation.

Anyway, just a thought.

Comment: Yeah... I'd thought about going the reusable Bitmap route... it just sounded like work :)  I'll see if I can figure out why it's constantly redrawing. I was kinda wondering if it was just what MapView did, or if I was having issues. Clearly I need to do more testing.

Answer (score 1):

There are two draw methods in the overlay class. One with 3 arguments and one with 4 arguments. You have to override the draw method with 3 arguments.
Overriding the method with 4 arguments will slow down your application. This is exactly, what happened to me. It seems, where are examples around in the internet with the same error.