# Overlay.draw() calls many times

Tags: android, maps, overlay

I have a question regarding the `draw()` method of the `Overlay` class in Android Maps.

When I move map, method `draw()` get called a few times (from 4 to 13). It's a problem for me, because this method must repaint my route with 70000+ points, and this is a lot resources.

I can't find description for this problem, but when I use code examples from any sources, I have same problem.

Comment: I think it not depends from code. You can get any source example with Android Maps, put breakpoint into draw() method and see this phenomenom. I can send all my source code (with layouts, manifest). I don't know how attach it to branch.

Comment: For the sake of clarity, it´s better to transfer your `new problem` bellow to a new question. And you will get more answer too :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [draw is being constantly called in my android map overlay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792263/draw-is-being-constantly-called-in-my-android-map-overlay)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the normal behaviour. When you move the map, you expect it to move smoothly and to achive that any map movement is slipt in smaller movement steps.

For the sake of consitency, the `draw()` method on the overlay is called for each of this small steps movement, so you can reposition your overlay items to follow each os this steps.

You can improve it using the following:

**Improvement 1**

For each of the small steps, `onDraw` is called twice. One with `shadow` parameter equal to `true`and one equal to `false`. If you are not drawing shadows you can just ignore one of the calls, and therefore reduce the overhead by 2, using the following as the first line of `onDraw()`:

```
if(shadow) return;
```

**Improvement 2**

Optimize the way you are drwaing the route. If you are using `canvas.drawLine()` you can definitly improve it by using `canvas.drawPath()`. You create a path with your route just once (for a specific zoom level) and when the map is moved you just offset the path, without the need to recreat it.

**Improvement 3**

You can even optimize further the path, only adding points that have a distance from previous pixel bigger a speciffic value (i.e. 2 pixels), reducing the total number of points in the path without any visible loss of quality.

I'm using the approach above with routes of several thousand points (aprox 20.000) and the route move smoothly in a medium range device.

Let me know if you need more details in any of the above points.

good luck.

Comment: hi @Luis, I am usuing OverylayView as well, but I cannot find the onDraw() method even in its API reference(https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#OverlayView). Could you please provide an example if possible? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you use

```
boolean draw(android.graphics.Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when)
```

and not

```
void draw(android.graphics.Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow)
```

The first one is used to draw animations, so it gets called many times.

Ref: [draw is being constantly called in my android map overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792263/draw-is-being-constantly-called-in-my-android-map-overlay)