# Android MapView overlay, caching bitmap on draw

Tags: android, caching, overlay, android-mapview, android-canvas

I have an overlay for drawing a path on my `MapView`, but i noticed it gets unnecessarily redrawn about ten times per second. 
Since in the `draw` method i draw every single segment of the path, this could easily be an efficiency issue.

For this reason i decided to cache the contents of the overlay and actually redraw it just when necessary, that is when the path changes, or the center of the map has moved, or the zoom level has changed.

Now, one of the parameters of the `draw` method is the `Canvas` to draw on. I know how to draw the cached bitmap on it, the problem is i don't know how to cache the content of the canvas on a bitmap.
I can't instantiate a new canvas, nor can i call `setBitmap` because the canvas in a `HardwareCanvas` and it throws an `UnsupportedOperationException` if that method is invoked.

So, to recap, i have a canvas and a bitmap, how can i copy the canvas' content to the bitmap?

**Edit**
this is my draw method for clarity, i don't invoke it manually but still it gets called repeatedly even when the map is not moving at all

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView map, boolean shadow) {
    if (shadow) {  
        // this overlay doesn't need to draw shadows  
        return;
    }
    if (paths.isEmpty()) {
        // nothing to draw
        return;
    }
    center = map.getMapCenter();
    zoomLevel = map.getZoomLevel();
    map.getDrawingRect(bounds);
    projection = map.getProjection();
    maxLevel = map.getMaxZoomLevel();
    for (MapPath mp : paths) {
        // adjust path width to current zoom
        adjustedWidth = mp.getWidth() * zoomLevel / maxLevel;
        if (adjustedWidth < MIN_WIDTH_TO_DRAW) {
            // path is too thin, avoid drawing it
            continue;
        }
        paint.setStrokeWidth(adjustedWidth);
        paint.setColor(mp.getColor());
        state = PathState.FIRST_POINT;
        path.reset();
        for (PathPoint pp : mp.getPoints()) {
            if (!pp.shoudAppearAtZoomLevel(zoomLevel)) {
                // do not draw this point at this zoom level
                continue;
            }
            // project a geopoint to a pixel
            projection.toPixels(pp.getGeoPoint(), point);
            inside = isInsideBounds(point, map);
            switch (state) {
            case FIRST_POINT:
                // move to starting point
                firstX = point.x;
                firstY = point.y;
                path.moveTo(firstX, firstY);
                break;
            case WAS_INSIDE:
                // segment is completely or partially on map
                path.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
                break;
            case WAS_OUTSIDE:
                if (inside) {
                    // segment is partially on map
                    path.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
                } else {
                    // segment is completely off map
                    path.moveTo(point.x, point.y);
                }
                break;
            }
            // update state
            state = inside ? PathState.WAS_INSIDE : PathState.WAS_OUTSIDE;
        }
        // workaround to avoid canvas becoming too big when path is mostly off screen
        path.moveTo(firstX, firstY);
        // draw this path to canvas
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }
    super.draw(canvas, map, shadow);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get the bitmap to where the `Mapview`canvas is drawing.

The approach should be following:

- First you create your own (empty and transparent) bitmap, with the same size as the `MapView` canvas
- Then you create your won canvas for your bitmap (this canvas is the drawing tool that you are using to draw to your bitmap) and you draw the path using it.
- Finally you draw your bitmap (with the path already drawn) to the `MapView` canvas.

However the performance/efficiency issues you are refering are probably due to incorrect design of your existing solution. I can draw paths with 10.000 points without using bitmap (and there are a few good reasons to not use them) in about 3ms in a medium range device.

There are a few hints on how to approach it, on my answer to this post: [Overlay.draw() calls many times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12931564/overlay-draw-calls-many-times/12936520#12936520). Check also the answer from @shkschneider in the same post.

--EDITED--

Just by looking at the code, I can't figure out why you are getting this warning ... But are making it much more complex then it needs to be.

Organize you code in the following way:

**draw**

The `draw()`methos only checks if there is a zoom change (if so ask the path to be rebuild) and if map has moved (if so offset path) and finally draws the path.

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapview, boolean shadow) {
    super.draw(canvas, mapview, shadow);
    if(shadow) return;
    if(mp.getPoints() == null || mp.getPoints().size() < 2) return;

    Projection projection = mapview.getProjection();
    int lonSpanNew = projection.fromPixels(0,mapview.getHeight()/2).getLongitudeE6() - 
            projection.fromPixels(mapview.getWidth(),mapview.getHeight()/2).getLongitudeE6();
    if(lonSpanNew != pathInitialLonSpan)
        pathBuild();
    else{ //check if path need to be offset
        projection.toPixels(mp.getPoints().get(0), p1);
        if(p1.x != pathInitialPoint.x || p1.y != pathInitialPoint.y){
            path.offset(p1.x - pathInitialPoint.x, p1.y - pathInitialPoint.y);
            pathInitialPoint.x = p1.x;
            pathInitialPoint.y = p1.y;
        }

    }
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint); 
}
```

**pathBuild**

The path has to be built every time zoom changes. The zoom change detection is done using `pathInitialLonSpan` as `getZoomLevel()` is not shyncronous with map zoom animation.

```
private void pathBuild(){
    path.rewind(); 
    if(mp.getPoints() == null || mp.getPoints().size() < 2) return;

    Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
    pathInitialLonSpan = projection.fromPixels(0,mapView.getHeight()/2).getLongitudeE6() - 
            projection.fromPixels(mapView.getWidth(),mapView.getHeight()/2).getLongitudeE6();

    projection.toPixels(mp.getPoints().get(0), pathInitialPoint);
    path.moveTo(pathInitialPoint.x,pathInitialPoint.y); 

    for(int i=1; i<mp.getPoints().size(); i++){
        projection.toPixels(mp.getPoints().get(i), p1);
        int distance2 = (pPrev.x - p1.x) * (pPrev.x - p1.x) + (pPrev.y - p1.y) * (pPrev.y - p1.y); 
        if(distance2 > 9){
            path.lineTo(p1.x,p1.y);
            pPrev.set(p1.x, p1.y);
        }
    }
```

Some objects (i.e. p1, pPrev, etc) are defined at class level to avoid creating new ones everytime the methos runs.

`Note:` I've changed the variable names to fit the ones you are using. I hope I've not made any mistake, but you should be able to figure that out.

Regards.

Comment: i am not suffering from any slow down with my map, and i am pretty sure i did a good job with the design of my solution (i followed many best practices and also included several optimizations) it's just that i thought it would be more efficient to cache the resulting path instead of recomputing it ten times per second ad infinitum... however are you suggesting to avoid using bitmaps? can i ask you why?

Comment: I suggest you to recheck best practices ... First, the overlay is only drawn when map moves/zoom or by your request (not 10 times per second), second you can cache your route on a `Path` (although it is a bit slower on draw then a bitmap it uses a lot less memory and requires recalculation on zoom change, not with map move).

Comment: The disadvantages on using bitmap are: 1 - they require a lot os memory (width x height x 2 bytes if using ARGB8888) and memory for bitmap is maintained outside heap memory in devices prior to 3.0 and not efficiently collected by GC, resulting in out of memory exceptions (just goole for it). 2 - You will need to recalculate the bitmap everytime map moves (this is not need using `Path` object) because you will need to include in it a new part of the route that entres screen and remove the part that exist screen.

Comment: I'm not saying that it can't be done (I've done it myself to compare with the solution using a `Path`), but for a general route and map utilization it worse in memory utlization (bitmap size) and performance (more redraws), and increases code complexity.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explaination. I dunno why my draw is called so often, i'll have to investigate that. i used to cache the path as you suggested, but i experienced a problem:
on high zoom levels, when calling canvas.drawPath, the resulting bitmap would be so big that android refuses to draw it and prints a warning. how do you deal with this?
i had to discard this solution and make another one where only the portion of the path actually on screen is drawn, but this way i can't just offset the path when the map is scrolled around

Comment: Are you using `public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapview, boolean shadow)` or `public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapview, boolean shadow, long milliseconds)`. You should use the first, as the latter is called much more often.

Comment: I don't understand the issue you refer with `canvas.drawPath()`. The `Path` object is not a `Bitmap` and you should be drawing it to the bitmap holding the map using the MapView canvas, which do not change bitmap size or create any new bitmap object. Edit your question to add the code where you draw the path and I'll check it.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example. You don't need to use (or can change the value of) distance2. It avoids recording points that are less then 3 pixels away from the previous one.

Comment: As I said, you don't nee to use it. However, 3 pixels is less then 1/3 of a millimeter in hdpi device ... it's very hard to notice it ...